# Accessing private posts through REST API, same code that works in remote doesn't in local

Tags: rest-api, local-installation, private, post-status, windows

I am capable of fetching private posts through the wp rest api by calling

```
mydomain/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?status=private&slug=whatever
```

I am authenticating well and receiving a valid token, no problems

But with the same site running with Laragon (windows 10), while running ok with the authentication, I cannot retrieve the private posts

```
http://testing.test/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?status=private&slug=whatever

{
    "code": "rest_invalid_param",
    "message": "Invalid parameter(s): status",
    "data": {
        "status": 400,
        "params": {
            "status": "Status is forbidden."
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the same response (as expected) when using Postman and having the `Bearer token` header correctly configured

What's going on? I've run out of ideas

*I can retrieve public posts

Comment: [Here's the check](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.3.2/wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-posts-controller.php#L2604). Are you sure `current_user_can( $post_type_obj->cap->edit_posts ) || current_user_can( $post_type_obj->cap->read_private_posts )` ? It might be worth adding some error_log trace around those lines.

Comment: Yes, that was it, I didn't install a plugin that enabled what you say, thanks!

Comment: @GWorking can you write an answer explaining what the problem was and naming the plugin you needed? If other people have the same issue they're going to want to know what fixed things for you ( also I can't upvote your answer if you don't write one! )

Comment: Done (just waiting if @Rup wanted to post an answer)

Comment: No, there were lots more details than I had. Glad you solved it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't completely clone the wp site, and I forgot to install the plugin that I used to manage user roles

The plugin is Members ("User Role Editor by Members – Best User, Role and Capability Management Plugin for WordPress") by MemberPress, and there I can allow the roles that I want to have permissions to read private posts

Once that is done, the problem is gone